# Unable to create Graphics2d object from BufferedImage

Tags: clojure, bufferedimage, graphics2d

I have a `BufferedImage` object, created from `ByteArrayInputStream` with `(ImageIO/read)` function.
Now I want to paint some lines on this image, so at the beginning I create `Graphics2d` object like this:

```
(defn g2d (.createGraphics image))
```

And here strange thing happens, because my function freezes here in this step. It never returns, never throws an `Exception` nothing. I run this program on server:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_222"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_222-8u222-b10-1ubuntu1~18.04.1-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.222-b10, mixed mode)
```

How could I find a cause of this freeze? I also checked if this Java version is headless like this:

```
(java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment/isHeadless)
```

But that method returned `false`.

Comment: if it's not headless, it will try to setup an Xserver (or something of that sort). Do you have xvfb installed?

Comment: I'm not sure. Could you explain your idea?

Comment: if you use the Graphics API, Java wants to set up a graphical system. That's what is taking so long and it might fail (I don't know your Linux setup). As an alternative, use a virtual graphics environment. (like xvfb). Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39388037/java-awt-requires-x11-how-to-use-xvfb-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: This article from Oracle might come handy for a headless example on plain Java, which you can rewrite in Clojure: https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/javase/headless.html

Comment: Also check this answer for how to properly set headless mode programatically (if you are not passing the option from the command line): https://stackoverflow.com/a/2552470/483566

Answer (score 1):

Actually I had to write a separate Java program in order to see what was the problem. After seeing the Java exception I managed to solve this problem by unsetting Linux variable DISPLAY: `unset DISPLAY`.